# python работа с изображениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Нашел в интернете поиск лиц по фото.
Решил дописать чтобы можно было обработать много фото сразу.

```
import cv2

from glob import glob

for filename in glob('*.jpg'):
    image  = cv2.imread(filename)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:/haarcascade_fontalface_default.xml')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_gray)
    print(f"{len(faces)} лиц обнаружено на изображении.")
```

Выдает ошибку:

> C:>py img.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "img.py", line 9, in 
> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_gray)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) >C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-uzca7qz1\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Только начал изучение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас пропцщена буква 'r'

```
import cv2
from glob import glob


# установите свой путь vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
for filename in glob('D:/_Qt/__Qt/images/*.jpg'):

    image  = cv2.imread(filename)
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    #face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:/haarcascade_fontalface_default.xml')
# у вас пропцщена буква 'r' ------------------------------> v 
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(           #-----> v 
           'opencv_videos/Face_Frame_Rate_plot/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# установите свой путь ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_gray)
    print(f"{len(faces)} лиц обнаружено на изображении {filename}.")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

В этой строчке кода:

```
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

`cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` - вы 2 раза вызываете `color` возможно здесь иошибка.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).